# Jenkins cannot connect to android emulator

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator, android-emulator-plugin

I'm using Jenkins for continous integration on an android emulator to run instrumentation tests with the espresso framework. Unfortunately the server is not able to connect to the emulator. I have a master instance which delegates the push events from GitHub to the slave instance where the android sdk is installed. I installed the android-emulator-plugin and configured it like described. At first the Jenkins starts the emulator, but it cannot connect to it afterwards. This is the result:

[image]

I also cannot connect to the emulator when I'm on the slave machine. But if I use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost the adb tool can connect to the emulator:

[image]

Is it possible to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost with the android-emulator-plugin? I already specified the enviorment variables $ANDROID_AVD_DEVICE and $ANDROID_SERIAL with no result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by myself. I have checked out a fork on GitHub, which uses 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. This did work for connecting to the emulator but not for running the instrumentation tests. I do not use Jenkins plugins for the connection anymore. I make the build with a shell script which contains all commands to start the AVD and the gradle tasks. Works fine for me. But thank you for the advice. Maybe I will try to comment ipv6 aswell, if I have the time to work on the Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

I was fighting with it whole day. Just try to comment ipv6 in your /etc/hosts.